# error in mutate() when updating column using if else condition for distinct ID

Tags: r

I a using the following code but it is giving me error

```
UPDATED_PENALTY['HISTORIC_PENALTY'] <- ave(UPDATED_PENALTY$PENALTY, UPDATED_PENALTY$OFFICIAL_NUMBER, FUN=cumsum)
UPDATED_PENALTY['cum_prodsum']<-NA
UPDATED_PENALTY %>%
  mutate(cum_prodsum = ifelse(UPDATED_PENALTY$INSPECTION_CLEARED==TRUE, UPDATED_PENALTY$HISTORIC_PENALTY*0.9, UPDATED_PENALTY$HISTORIC_PENALTY*0.9 + UPDATED_PENALTY$PENALTY))
```

Error

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `cum_prodsum = ifelse(...)`.
x `cum_prodsum` must be size 12 or 1, not 32217.
i The error occurred in group 1: OFFICIAL_NUMBER = "XXXXX".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Also, I want to exclude first "HISTORIC PENALTY" of each "OFFICIAL NUMBER from manipulation and copy the value as it is, rest all apply the above.

Comment: You don't use `UPDATED_PENALTY$` inside tidyverse i.e. `UPDATED_PENALTY %>%
  mutate(cum_prodsum = ifelse(INSPECTION_CLEARED, HISTORIC_PENALTY*0.9, HISTORIC_PENALTY*0.9  + PENALTY))`  I think you have a goruped data and thus when you extract the whole column and update it returns this size error

Comment: @akrun no error now after removing UPDATED_PENALTY$ but cum_prodsum all values are NA

Comment: It could be a result of `HISTORIC_PENALTY` that you created earlier.  Without data, it is not clear.  You may use `dput` to show a reproducible example so that others can test

Comment: @akrun HISTORIC_PENALTY is giving me cumsum of PENALTY for all official_numbers as required, but next step is to update prod_cumsum by reducing HISTORIC_PENALTY by 10% when INSPECTION_CLEARED is TRUE as attempted in the code. is that still incomplete for context?

Comment: I guess your data may have different types or having some group attributes etc which we don't know without showing the structure  of data with `dput`

Comment: @akrun just added dput result, kindly check

Comment: I don't get NAs with your data `UPDATE_PENALTY %>% ungroup %>% mutate(cum_prodsum = ifelse(INSPECTION_CLEARED, HISTORIC_PENALTY*0.9, HISTORIC_PENALTY*0.9  + PENALTY)) %>% pull(cum_prodsum)#
 [1] 114.0   0.0 590.9  99.6  75.6 284.6 174.6 184.1 179.1 179.1 293.1 233.1 269.2 330.0 288.0 293.7 371.1 290.7 290.7 296.4 586.0 432.0 578.3 554.5 526.5
[26] 526.5 627.2 323.1 574.2 703.4 715.2 617.6 673.2 462.6 673.2 673.2 827.1 747.6 746.1 746.1 778.4 597.6 597.6 761.4 799.4 779.4`

Comment: @akrun I guess you are right, but your code is not adding a column in the TEST dataframe,  it is printing the result like you showed

Comment: You need to assign back i.e. `UPDATE_PENALTY <- UPDATE_PENALTY %>% ungroup %>% mutate(cum_prodsum = ifelse(INSPECTION_CLEARED, HISTORIC_PENALTY*0.9, HISTORIC_PENALTY*0.9  + PENALTY))`  The `pull` was used to extract the column to show the values here

Comment: @akrun Looks good so can I apply this for a bigger dataset? I just gave a TEST dput with only two OFFICIAL NUMBERS, and lastly how do I round off  prod_cumsum? I tried  %>%round(TEST$cum_prodsum) but gave error Error in Math.data.frame(list(OFFICIAL_NUMBER = c("170718", "803729",  : 
  non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame: OFFICIAL_NUMBER
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `cum_prodsum`

Comment: You need `UPDATE_PENALTY <- UPDATE_PENALTY %>% mutate(cum_prodsum = round(cum_prodsum))`

Comment: @akrun I want to exclude entries where INSPECTION_COUNT = 1 I think, I mentioned it in the question at the end, is there a way to do that also?

Comment: Do you want to filter out or have the condition in ifelse i.e. `UPDATE_PENALTY %>% ungroup %>% mutate(cum_prodsum = ifelse(INSPECTION_CLEARED & INSPECTION_COUNT != 1, HISTORIC_PENALTY*0.9, HISTORIC_PENALTY*0.9  + PENALTY))`

Comment: @akrun have a condition in ifelse  when inspection count = 1 then cum_prodsum = Historic penalty  and for rest working like above

Comment: Try the update in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
UPDATE_PENALTY <- UPDATE_PENALTY %>%
        ungroup %>% 
        mutate(cum_prodsum = case_when(INSPECTION_COUNT == 1 
   ~ HISTORIC_PENALTY, 
    INSPECTION_CLEARED ~ HISTORIC_PENALTY*0.9, 
     TRUE  ~HISTORIC_PENALTY*0.9  + PENALTY))
```

-output

```
UPDATE_PENALTY
# A tibble: 46 × 7
   OFFICIAL_NUMBER NUM_DEF PENALTY INSPECTION_COUNT INSPECTION_CLEARED HISTORIC_PENALTY cum_prodsum
   <chr>             <dbl>   <dbl>            <int> <lgl>                         <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 170718               14      60                1 FALSE                            60        60  
 2 803729                0       0                1 TRUE                              0         0  
 3 803729               65     311                2 FALSE                           311       591. 
 4 170718                8      24                2 FALSE                            84        99.6
 5 170718                0       0                3 TRUE                             84        75.6
 6 170718               39     110                4 FALSE                           194       285. 
 7 170718                0       0                5 TRUE                            194       175. 
 8 170718                1       5                6 FALSE                           199       184. 
 9 170718                0       0                7 TRUE                            199       179. 
10 170718                0       0                8 TRUE                            199       179. 
# … with 36 more rows
```